# Fail2ban regex: how to NOT get host name but ip?

Tags: fail2ban

In my `access.log` I got somerow a

```
ip - - [date] method link ... etc..
```

and some others with

```
www.domain.com:ip - - [date] method link ... etc..
```

I am actually using this regexp

```
 ^<HOST>.*/phpmyadmin
```

The problem is that It causes that fail2ban uses as ip the reverse lookup of www.domain.com when parsing the second kind of rows.

Is there a more precise regexp for ip and not host name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to tell fail2ban to [not do hostname lookups](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Hostnames_or_IP_Addresses).

```
use_dns
yes   (current behavior)
warn  (uses but warns upon each dns lookup)
no    (no DNS lookup, no warnings, INFO-LEVEL log messages when
       rDNS was necessary and entry was ignored because of that)
```